# How to dynamically update the argument of OOTB hibernate validator annotations?

Tags: java, validation, annotations, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I use the `@Min` annotation for field validation.

```
@Min(100)
private Long cost;
```

I want to extract the argument of the annotation in a separate configuration file.

Is there way to achieve it?

### P.S.

I understrand that I can write my own annotation and my own validator but I want to reuse a library's code.

Comment: mmm ... so you want to pass a dynamic value to compile time argument, right? Since java removes the annotation related code in actual class files, you need to add the argument from configuration file at the compile time itself, so I think the only way is writing your own annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way to do it with annotations like @Min, @Max and so on. You can use [@AssertTrue](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/3.1.0/api/org/hibernate/validator/AssertTrue.html) to annotate a method of your entity in which your own validation logic will be implemented.

```
public class MyEntity {
     private Long cost;

     //getters and setters...
     @AssertTrue
     public boolean isValid() {
          long minCost = MyExternalConfig.getMinCost(); //get data from where you want
          return cost > minCost; 
     }

}
```